# Basic WebCrawler in Java using CompletableFuture returns empty-response

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8

Here is my code for the mock web-crawler using CompletableFuture, but returns empty-response.
Can someone please help me whats wrong?

```
class Solution {
    public List<String> crawl(String startUrl, HtmlParser htmlParser) {
        final Set<String> doneSet = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
        final String calledDomain = getDomain(startUrl);
        try {
            return this.crawlHelper(startUrl, htmlParser, doneSet, calledDomain);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

    }

    public List<String> crawlHelper(final String url,
                                    final HtmlParser parser,
                                    final Set<String> doneSet,
                                    final String calledDomain) {
        if (doneSet.contains(url)) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        doneSet.add(url);

        try {
            return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> parser.getUrls(url))
                    .thenApplyAsync(childUrls -> crawlChildren(childUrls, parser, doneSet, calledDomain)).get();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
    }

    public List<String> crawlChildren(final List<String> childUrls,
                                      final HtmlParser parser,
                                      final Set<String> doneSet,
                                      final String calledDomain) {
        try {
            return childUrls.stream()
                    .filter(curl -> !doneSet.contains(curl))
                    .filter(curl -> getDomain(curl).equals(calledDomain))
                    .map(curl -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> crawlHelper(curl, parser, doneSet, calledDomain)))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
                    .stream()
                    .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                    .flatMap(List::stream)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
    }

    private String getDomain(final String url) {
        return url.replace("http://", "").split("/")[0];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution sol = new Solution();
        HtmlParser parser = new HtmlParser();
        System.out.println(sol.crawl("http://news.yahoo.com/news/topics/", parser));
    }
}
```

Here is the Mock-Html-parser code, just for better understanding:

```
public class HtmlParser {
    private static Map<String, List<String>> ret = new HashMap<String, List<String>>(){
        {
            put("http://new.yahoo.com", Arrays.asList("http://news.yahoo.com/news/topics/", "http://new.yahoo.com"));
            put("http://news.yahoo.com/news", Arrays.asList("http://news.yahoo.com/news/topics/", "http://new.yahoo.com/news"));
            put("http://news.yahoo.com/news/topics/", Arrays.asList("http://news.yahoo.com/news/topics/", "http://news.google.com"));
            put("http://news.google.com", Arrays.asList("http://news.google.com", "http://news.yahoo.com/news"));
            put("http://news.yahoo.com/us", Arrays.asList("http://news.yahoo.com/us", "http://news.yahoo.com"));
        }
    };

    public List<String> getUrls(String url) {
        return ret.get(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your expected result? by debugging it seems true.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is remove all of your try/catch statements.  If something goes wrong, you need to know about it, and exceptions are an excellent way to know what’s gone wrong and where.  Suppressing them prevents you (and us) from having that knowledge.